# When trying jetpack compose it show error: compiler backend and cannot be loaded by the old compiler

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Class 'androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView' is compiled by a new Kotlin compiler backend and cannot be loaded by the old compiler

This my onCreate method :

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_delivered, container, false).apply {
        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Surface {
                    Text("Hello")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compose version:

```
accompanistVersion = "0.1.9"
composeVersion = '0.1.0-dev17'
```

app.gradle

```
buildFeatures {
        compose true
        dataBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion rootProject.kotlinVersion
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion rootProject.composeVersion
    }



// Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:compose-theme-adapter:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-coil:$rootProject.accompanistVersion"
```

Answer (score 20):

The default `app/build.grade`, when creating a new project with an "Empty Compose Activity", includes the following options.

```
android {
    // other options

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }

    // more options
}
```

Adding these options (specifically `useIR = true`) seemed to fix the error for me.

---

The `useIR` option references a [new JVM backend](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#new-jvm-ir-backend) for Kotlin for which the documentation specifically states the following.

> If you enable Jetpack Compose, you will automatically be opted in to the new JVM backend without needing to specify the compiler option in `kotlinOptions`.

Which is seemingly incorrect.

Comment: > "When using the command-line compiler, add the compiler option -Xuse-ir." . https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html

Comment: Adding useIR = true solved it for me. Any idea on what exactly useIR does?

Comment: @capt.swag it enables the new [JVM unified IR backend](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#unified-backends-and-extensibility), which is required for Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 19):

Please add this task in your app/build.gradle file:

```kotlin
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies", "-Xskip-prerelease-check"]
    }
}
```

Comment: As to why these compiler arguments are needed: while Jetpack Compose is still in alpha, these suppress errors when using dependencies that were compiled by the new IR backend and when using classes that are not yet released. (https://github.com/android/compose-samples/issues/120#issuecomment-681289777)

Answer (score 4):

Following the steps in the [official setup guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) lead me to the same problem.

Adding the necessary [dependencies/configuration for the compose library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose) fixed this issue for me.

Comment: The tasks.withType section is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

.kts version

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf(
        *kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs.toTypedArray(),
        "-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies",
        "-Xskip-prerelease-check")
    useIR = true
}
```

Comment: Minor comment: I had to add kotlinOptions. before useIR.

Answer (score 0):

This is the dependency which causes respective error in my case:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.5'
```

My guess that playing with it should help

Answer (score 0):

find kotlin compatible version [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Update dependency in build.gradle

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${version}"
```

here `${version}` is kotlin version.

Configure a suitable JDK version in Gradle Setting.
[image]

Run below commands

```
gradle clean

gradle build
```

For me, it resolved my issue.

*Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.*